# How to dynamically update bootstrap editable select input after page load using jquery?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have following template:

```
<div class="container">

  <h1>X-editable starter template</h1>

  <div>
    <span>Username:</span>
    <a href="#" id="username" data-type="text" data-placement="right" data-title="Enter username">superuser</a>
  </div>

  <div>
    <span>Status:</span>
    <a href="#" id="status"></a>
  </div>


</div>
```

JS code follows here :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//toggle `popup` / `inline` mode
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';     

//make username editable
$('#username').editable();

//make status editable
$('#status').editable({
    emptytext: 'Leer',
    type: 'select',
    title: 'Select status',
    placement: 'right',

    source: [
        {value: 1, text: 'status 1'},
        {value: 2, text: 'status 2'},
        {value: 3, text: 'status 3'}
    ]

});
});
```

What I want to do is that to update status dropdown with some new values like 5,6,7 which should replace/remove 1,2,3 using jquery. Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you want to change dropdown menu on sub button click???

Comment: Actually, I want to change all the values of drop down to some new values after page load through some ajax call or jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use PHP with ajax jquery.

Simple create file `xxx.php`

```
$test = array(
 0=>array('value'=>"1",'text'=>'Status 5'),
 1=>array('value'=>"2",'text'=>'Status 6'),
 2=>array('value'=>"3",'text'=>'Status 7')
);
print_r(json_encode($test));
```

PHP response will be:

```
[{
    "value": "1",
    "text": "Status 5"
}, {
    "value": "2",
    "text": "Status 6"
}, {
    "value": "3",
    "text": "Status 7"
}]
```

In Jquery use this response as values:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //toggle `popup` / `inline` mode
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

    //make username editable
    $('#username').editable();

    //make status editable
    $.post('xxx.php', '', function (res) {
        $('#status').editable({
            emptytext: 'Leer',
            type: 'select',
            title: 'Select status',
            placement: 'right',
            source: res
        });
    });
});
```